# Dynamically group table rows by value

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, html-table, jstl

i have two array:

```
<%String TXTfileArray[] = (String[])request.getAttribute("txt");%>    
<%String sentenceArray[] = (String[])request.getAttribute("sentence");%>
```

by using the following:

```
<body>

<h1>Table of Phone Numbers</h1>
<table border="1">

 <tr>
    <th>txt name</th>
    <th>sentence</th>
  </tr>

   <% for (int i=0; i< sentenceArray.length;i++){ %>

  <tr>
    <td> <%=TXTfileArray[i] %>  </td>    
     <td> <%=sentenceArray[i] %>  </td>   <%} %> 

   </tr>


 </table>
</body>
```

I can get the result as :

[image: the result i got]

so how to change the table, since there is duplicated txt name in the table, how to remove the duplicated txt name. to keep unique txt name in the column (such as merget the cell)

I want to get the result as following.

[image]

if can change the output, how to do it in JSTL tags?

Answer (score -1):

Check the below code. It may help to fulfill your requirement.

JSBin link : https://jsbin.com/?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
      <table id="tblExample" border="1px" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Group</th><th>Sub Group</th><th>Details</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Group#1</td><td>Sub-Group#1</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#1</td><td>Sub-Group#2</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#1</td><td>Sub-Group#3</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#2</td><td>Sub-Group#1</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#2</td><td>Sub-Group#2</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#3</td><td>Sub-Group#1</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#4</td><td>Sub-Group#1</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#4</td><td>Sub-Group#2</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#4</td><td>Sub-Group#3</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group#5</td><td>Sub-Group#1</td><td>Some description here.........</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#tblExample').each(function () {
            var Column_number_to_Merge = 1;
 
            // Previous_TD holds the first instance of same td. Initially first TD=null.
            var Previous_TD = null;
            var i = 1;
            $("tbody",this).find('tr').each(function () {
                // find the correct td of the correct column
                // we are considering the table column 1, You can apply on any table column
                var Current_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + Column_number_to_Merge + ')');
                 
                if (Previous_TD == null) {
                    // for first row
                    Previous_TD = Current_td;
                    i = 1;
                } 
                else if (Current_td.text() == Previous_TD.text()) {
                    // the current td is identical to the previous row td
                    // remove the current td
                    Current_td.remove();
                    // increment the rowspan attribute of the first row td instance
                    Previous_TD.attr('rowspan', i + 1);
                    i = i + 1;
                } 
                else {
                    // means new value found in current td. So initialize counter variable i
                    Previous_TD = Current_td;
                    i = 1;
                }
            });
        });  
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use HTML <td> rowspan attribute to specifies the number of rows a cell should span.

```
E.g.:

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>txt name</th>
    <th>sentence</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>txt1</td>
    <td>apple from one</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">txt6</td>
    <td>six trees</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>        
    <td>cats</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>    
    <td>happy dogs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```